# Counter metrics in GCP metrics explorer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, metrics, google-cloud-monitoring

I have a DataFlow job with a counter metric. On every restart the metric is reset to zero, as expected. The problem is that when using the counter in gcp Metrics explorer, I cannot get an accumulated value for the metric, disregarding restarts. Prometheus has a function called increase() that does this. Is there a similar function for gcp metrics explorer?

Comment: I have the opposite problem: I need my counters to reset to zero occasionally. Can you you please explain how you are getting your counter to reset to zero? What do you mean by "restart"? Are you just redeploying DataFlow?

Answer (score 0):

One approuch to metrics across runs would be to make use of [Cloud Monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring). There is a good [how to](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/using-cloud-monitoring) on the features and usage of custom metrics.

If you use job names that you can apply a regexp to then you can make use of the filters to aggregate them into a graph.